# How to show average number of changes in a two-states Markov Chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, asymptotics, markov-chains, entropy

Assuming we have two states $0$ and $1$. The probability to stay in the same state is $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ to go into the other state.

Or simply put as a probabilistic transition matrix $P$:

\begin{align*}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}

We're also given $p(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$:

\begin{align*}
p_{n+1}(x_0,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{1}{2} \Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^w \Big(\frac{3}{4} \Big)^{n-w}
\end{align*}

Where $w$ is the number changes from $0 \rightarrow 1$ or $1 \rightarrow 0$ in $x_0,\ldots,x_n$.

Using the definition of the [asymptotic equipartition property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_equipartition_property) (AEP):

\begin{align*}
A_\epsilon^{(n+1)} := \Big| - \frac{1}{n} \log_2 p(x_0,\ldots,x_n) - H(X) \Big| < \epsilon
\end{align*}

Where

\begin{align*}
H(X) = - \frac{1}{4} \log_2 \frac{1}{4} - \frac{3}{4} \log_2 \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}

is the entropy of $X$.

I should be able to show that $\frac{w}{n} \in \Big(\frac{1}{4} - \epsilon', \frac{1}{4} + \epsilon' \Big)$ where $\frac{w}{n}$ is the average number of changes between the states $0$ and $1$.
Unfortunately I am failing to do so. Could anybody show me how I can get to this result?

Comment: Who is $\varepsilon'$? Also, consider that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P^n = \begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\\frac12&\frac12\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: @Math1000 I think $\epsilon'$ is just $\epsilon + c$ and I guess $c$ emerges through executing the necessary calculations. However, I am not 100% sure about this. Unfortunately I have rather incomplete notes on this part hence I try to understand how I get to this result.

Comment: @Math1000 I'm sorry but can you elaborate your hint a bit? I'm currently trying to understand the whole chapter about asymptotic entropy and for some reason I keep *not* understanding the Markov Chain examples. What exactly am I looking at $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P^n$ ?

Comment: To use AEP to prove that $$\frac{w}n\approx\frac14$$ is very odd (and probably circular) but, anyway, you are asked to note, first, that the *definition* of the AEP is equivalent to $$2^{-n(H(x)+\epsilon)}\leqslant p(x_0,\ldots,x_n)\leqslant2^{-n(H(x)-\epsilon)}$$ second, that the *definition* of $p(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ is $$p(x_0,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{1}{2} \Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^w \Big(\frac{3}{4} \Big)^{n-w}$$ and third, that the *definition* of $H(X)$ means $$2^{-H(X)}=\left(\frac14\right)^{1/4}\left(\frac34\right)^{3/4}$$ Putting these ...

Comment: ...  three *definitions* together yields $$2^{-n\epsilon}\left(\frac14\right)^{n/4}\left(\frac34\right)^{3n/4}\leqslant \frac{1}{2} \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^w \Big(\frac{3}{4} \Big)^{n}\leqslant2^{n\epsilon}\left(\frac14\right)^{n/4}\left(\frac34\right)^{3n/4}\qquad(\ast)$$ and now, everything reduces to a little bit of algebraic massaging of $(\ast)$. To wit, $(\ast)$ is equivalent to ...

Comment: $$2^{-n\epsilon}\frac12\Big(\frac{3}{4} \Big)^{n}\left(\frac14\right)^{-n/4}\left(\frac34\right)^{-3n/4}\leqslant 3^w\leqslant2^{n\epsilon}\frac12\Big(\frac{3}{4} \Big)^{n}\left(\frac14\right)^{-n/4}\left(\frac34\right)^{-3n/4}$$ that is, $$2^{-n\epsilon-1}3^{n/4}\leqslant 3^w\leqslant2^{n\epsilon-1}3^{n/4}$$ which means exactly that $$-(n\epsilon+1)\log_32+\tfrac14n\leqslant w\leqslant(n\epsilon-1)\log_32+\tfrac14n$$ that is, ...

Comment: $$\frac14-\left(\epsilon+\frac1n\right)\log_32\leqslant \frac{w}n\leqslant\frac14+\left(\epsilon-\frac1n\right)\log_32$$ hence, indeed, $(\ast)$ implies that $$\frac{w}n\approx\frac14$$

Comment: @Did Thank you! Definitely helps but why not provide an answer? :)